# Under what conditions will a numerically-computed Jacobian differ from an analytical one?

Tags: numerical-methods, jacobian

Say you have $y = f(\mathbf{X, \theta})$ and you want $\partial y_i/\partial \mathbf{\theta}$ at the optimized value of $\theta$.  Further assume that it is feasible -- but a hassle -- to calculate these derivatives analytically, and simple to compute a numerical Jacobian, using for example `jacobian` in the `numDeriv` package in R.

Under what conditions is the analytical approach preferable?  Given that these are just first derivatives -- slope coefs -- it seems like the numerical approach should always work just fine, and avoid any risk of pencil-and-paper mistakes.  Is this correct?

Comment: Any numerical differentiation comes with an error, which may potentially be hard to control. Also, under some circumstances it can be faster to use an analytical Jacobian if you can do the analysis in advance (i.e. "offline"). Note that this analysis can often be done in a CAS. It could also happen that the analytical approach gives you some actual information that can easily be missed in the sea of numbers that numerical computation often generates.

Comment: @Ian that is true in general, but if I want $\partial y_i / \partial\theta$, *for unit i*, how can I make an error by simply changing $\theta$ and seeing what I get for $y_i$?

Comment: What? I don't understand what you mean at all. $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial \theta}$ is a partial derivative, so it corresponds to an "infinitesimal" change in $\theta$. We cannot achieve this in finite precision arithmetic; we are forced to take merely a small change to avoid the precision of our arithmetic causing even worse errors. Consider for example the difference between $(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=2x$. They're not the same.

Comment: I had been thinking of it as a linear approximation, rather than an infinitesimal change.  So I guess the answer to my question is that it depends on the support.

Comment: It really doesn't. When you do numerical differentiation you take a finite change of the independent variable in order to estimate the best local linear approximation of the function, and in the process you *don't get* the best local linear approximation but rather just a (hopefully) good linear approximation. For example, the true tangent line to $y=x^2$ at $(2,4)$ is $y=4(x-2)+4$. If you estimate the derivative there as $\frac{(2+h)^2-2^2}{h}$, you would conclude that it is instead $y=(4+h)(x-2)+4$, which is not the same.